# I am using git lab api but I don't know how to request BOOLEAN type value

Tags: git, api, request, boolean, gitlab

I am using git lab api and I want to get all commit lists.

This one.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#list-repository-commits

and this is my request url:

```
https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/(repository)/repository/commits?private_token=(private key)&all=true
```

But it responds only recent 20 commits.

So I did also these:

```
all = True
all = 1
all = TRUE
```

But it doesn't work well.

I need help.

Comment: Isn't the response paginated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `per_page` query string parameter (don't know if it has a value like `-1` to retrieve all or if you need to specify a very high value or if you have an API to retrieve commits count).
IIRC it is setted to 20 by default.